# Google Maps not displaying in wordpress using Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: theme-development, javascript, api, google-maps

I was wondering if someone could help me out. I am currently trying to set up the google maps Javascript API to work with wordpress on a localhost but i have had no luck. Please find my steps below.

-Step 1: I went to the Google Developer API Manager and enable an api for Google Maps Javascript API.

-Step 2: I generated an API Key.

-Step 3: I enqued the maps Javascript API like so and included the API key where it says key={MY API KEY} :

```
 if ( ! function_exists( 'foundationpress_scripts' ) ) :
        function foundationpress_scripts() {



     //Load Google Maps API   
        wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={MY API KEY}' );


 //Load custom JS script    
     wp_enqueue_script('custom-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/javascript/custom/custom-scripts.js', array(), '1.0.0', true ); 


    // Add the comment-reply library on pages where it is necessary
        if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
        }

        }

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foundationpress_scripts' );
    endif;
```

-Step 4: I created  a custom-scripts.js file and loaded to the directory i enqued it to.

-Step 5: I added

```
 var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
```

to the custom-scripts.js file.

Step 6: I created a template page and linked it to a page inside the dashboard and added `<div id="map-canvas"></div>`.

I am not receiving any WP_DEBUG errors nor am I receiving any developers console errors. Does anyone know why this is happening. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you verified that your map implementation is working outside of WordPress (in a static page, for example)? Knowing that your map works on localhost independently would be helpful. It does appear that your `custom-scripts` JS should specify your `google-maps` script as a dependency though.

Comment: hey @DaveRomsey, I have tested the API on a static HTML doc and it is working, I am even getting info back on the Developer's API console. However it is still not working in my wordpress theme. I am still recieving no errors in the developers console.

Comment: Are you creating a child theme for Foundation Press? If so, and the function `foundationpress_scripts()` exists in the parent theme, your code will not run. Remove the `function_exists()` conditional check around your function. Note that this will override the parent theme's `foundationpress_scripts()` function. If you don't want that to happen, rename your `foundationpress_scripts()` to something else.

Comment: hey @DaveRomsey I am not building a child theme, FoundationPress is barebones so you could just develop on top. I have registered other scripts and they are running fine. I checked my developer's console and the api is loading in the head with all the necessary files, and I do not have a single error. But the map will not display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get this working after a bit of fiddling. Give the `#map-canvas` element a height (you can do this in CSS):

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="height:500px"></div>
```

Add the `callback` argument to the `google-maps` script URL and add the `defer` and `async` attributes to the `google-maps` script tag. Also make `custom-scripts` a dependency for `google-maps`:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'foundationpress_scripts' ) ) :
function foundationpress_scripts() {
    //Load custom JS script    
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/javascript/custom/custom-scripts.js', array(), '1.0.0', true ); 

    // Load Google Maps API. Make sure to add the callback and add custom-scripts dependency
    wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap',  array( 'custom-scripts' ) ); 

    // Add the comment-reply library on pages where it is necessary
    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'foundationpress_scripts' );
endif;

// Add async and defer attributes
function google_maps_script_attributes( $tag, $handle) {
    if ( 'google-maps' !== $handle ) {
        return $tag;
  }
    return str_replace( ' src', ' async="async" defer src', $tag );
}
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'google_maps_script_attributes', 10, 2);
```

Make sure to do a hard reload in your browser after fixing everything.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I am experiencing an error and i think it is due to the maps loading on every page, but the map div is not on all the pages only the contact page, how could i get rid of this errror? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Comment: You could wrap the calls to `wp_enqueue_script()` with a conditional statement, such as  `is_page_template()` or `is_page()` using a similar pattern to what is done with the `comment-reply` script. This also might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740663/google-map-api-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-offsetwidth-of-null